# Cant edit excel file in Sharepoint because it has Comments, Shapes, or other objects

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an excel sheet in a Sharepoint which is no longer editable in browser because Sharepoint complains that there are "Comments, Shapes, or other objects" and that is apparently not supported. I'm 99% sure what whatever it is, it doesn't need to be there.

Is there anyway I could quickly find and delete whatever is causing this issue? Its a pretty big excel sheet, so I don't want to go through it line by line, especially if I dont even know what IM looking for.

Answer (score 2):

On the right end of the home ribbon there is button labelled "Find & Select" which opens a dropdown. The bottom option of the dropdown is "Selection Pane" which opens a sidebar listing all the comments, shapes etc for the whole file, so you can locate and delete anything you don't need.

(I'm using Excel 2013 but I think it is the same in 2010).

[image: find & select menu]

---

EDIT: this is how it looks when it finds something:
[image: results]

Comment: Weird... it doesnt actually show anything.

Comment: That is weird.  I've updated my answer to show how it looks when it does find shapes and comments.  I guess you have some mystery other object(s) that are not detected.

Comment: Does your Sharepoint have [version history](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/view-the-version-history-of-an-item-or-file-HA010148860.aspx) enabled?  You could use that to try to find the point where it stopped being browser-editable and see what the preceeding change was maybe?

Comment: It does, but the sheet is old and we make a new copy of it everyone once in a while, so its hard to trace down. I found that saving copy of it inside sharepoint makes it remove the objects, so that works.